# About using xs:unique on xsi:type in a sequence

Tags: xsd, unique

It is possible to have a unique constraint on an element's type ?

Let's say I have a Noah's Ark where Animal/@name must be unique.

Below's an XML that do not validate against the schema:

```
<ns:NoahsArk xmlns:ns="http://www.xxx.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="http://www.xxx.com Persons.xsd"> 
    <Animal xs:type="ns:Dog" ns:name="Gipsy" ns:pedigree="caniche"/>
    <Animal xs:type="ns:Spider" ns:name="Gipsy" ns:legNumber="5"/>
</ns:NoahsArk>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns="http://www.xxx.com"
targetNamespace="http://www.xxx.com" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified"> 
    <xs:element name="NoahsArk">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Animal" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ns:Animal"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:unique name="NameUnicity">
            <xs:selector xpath="Animal"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@ns:name"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="Animal" abstract="true">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Dog">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ns:Animal">
                <xs:attribute name="pedigree" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Spider">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ns:Animal">
                <xs:attribute name="legNumber" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>    
</xs:schema>
```

That's good but now let's say I want an Noah's Ark where Animal/@xsi:type are unique.

I tried this constraint:

```
<xs:unique name="AnimalUnicity">
    <xs:selector xpath="Animal"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@xs:type"/>
</xs:unique>
```

But this XML is still valid :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:NoahsArk xmlns:ns="http://www.xxx.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="http://www.xxx.com Persons.xsd">
    <Animal xs:type="ns:Dog" ns:name="Pierre-Louis" ns:pedigree="doberman"/>
    <Animal xs:type="ns:Spider" ns:name="Gipsy" ns:legNumber="5"/>
</ns:NoahsArk>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks,
-E

Answer (score 0):

All the implementations I could test on XSD 1.0 seem to agree on one thing here: the [identity constraints](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cIdentity-constraint_Definitions) will be tested only if the selectors/fields match XML nodes for which an associated **user defined** schema component can be found. [xsi:type](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type), while it is a schema related markup, is not considered here since its intention is different. It might prove academically interesting to check if a Schematron assertion might help here...

UPDATE: I am including the Schematron version, too; I am running the ISO version, XSLT1 w/ Microsoft extensions since I am on .NET.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <sch:ns uri="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" prefix="xsi"/>
    <sch:ns uri="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" prefix="ms"/>

   <sch:pattern id="about-using-xsunique-on-xsitype-in-a-sequence">
      <sch:rule context="//Animal/@xsi:type">
        <sch:let name="targetNodeSet" value="//Animal/@xsi:type"/>
        <sch:assert test="count($targetNodeSet[concat('{', ms:namespace-uri(.), '}', ms:local-name(.)) = concat('{', ms:namespace-uri(current()), '}', ms:local-name(current()))]) = 1">
            Only one-of-a-kind animal is allowed.</sch:assert>
        <sch:assert test="count($targetNodeSet[. = current()]) = 1">
            Only one-of-a-kind animal is allowed (naive).</sch:assert>
      </sch:rule>
   </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

I've defined two assertion, a "naive" one that textually compares the value of the xsi:type attribute; and the "correct" one which compares them as **QName** s.

For this XML:

```
<ns:NoahsArk xmlns:ns1="http://www.xxx.com" xmlns:ns="http://www.xxx.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:schemaLocation="http://www.xxx.com Persons.xsd">  
    <Animal xs:type="ns:Dog" ns:name="A" ns:pedigree="caniche"/> 
    <Animal xs:type="ns1:Dog" ns:name="B" ns:pedigree="caniche"/> 
    <Animal xs:type="ns1:Dog" ns:name="C" ns:pedigree="caniche"/> 
</ns:NoahsArk>
```

This is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<svrl:schematron-output title="" schemaVersion="" xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:schold="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values uri="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" prefix="xsi"/>
    <svrl:ns-prefix-in-attribute-values uri="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" prefix="ms"/>
    <svrl:active-pattern id="about-using-xsunique-on-xsitype-in-a-sequence" name="about-using-xsunique-on-xsitype-in-a-sequence"/>
    <svrl:fired-rule context="//Animal/@xsi:type"/>
    <svrl:failed-assert test="count($targetNodeSet[concat(', ms:namespace-uri(.), ', ms:local-name(.)) = concat(', ms:namespace-uri(current()), ', ms:local-name(current()))]) = 1" location="/@*[local-name()='type' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance']">
        <svrl:text>
            Only one-of-a-kind animal is allowed.</svrl:text>
    </svrl:failed-assert>
    <svrl:fired-rule context="//Animal/@xsi:type"/>
    <svrl:failed-assert test="count($targetNodeSet[concat(', ms:namespace-uri(.), ', ms:local-name(.)) = concat(', ms:namespace-uri(current()), ', ms:local-name(current()))]) = 1" location="/@*[local-name()='type' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance']">
        <svrl:text>
            Only one-of-a-kind animal is allowed.</svrl:text>
    </svrl:failed-assert>
    <svrl:failed-assert test="count($targetNodeSet[. = current()]) = 1" location="/@*[local-name()='type' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance']">
        <svrl:text>
            Only one-of-a-kind animal is allowed (naive).</svrl:text>
    </svrl:failed-assert>
    <svrl:fired-rule context="//Animal/@xsi:type"/>
    <svrl:failed-assert test="count($targetNodeSet[concat(', ms:namespace-uri(.), ', ms:local-name(.)) = concat(', ms:namespace-uri(current()), ', ms:local-name(current()))]) = 1" location="/@*[local-name()='type' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance']">
        <svrl:text>
            Only one-of-a-kind animal is allowed.</svrl:text>
    </svrl:failed-assert>
    <svrl:failed-assert test="count($targetNodeSet[. = current()]) = 1" location="/@*[local-name()='type' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance']">
        <svrl:text>
            Only one-of-a-kind animal is allowed (naive).</svrl:text>
    </svrl:failed-assert>
</svrl:schematron-output>
```

As you can see from the failed assertions, the "naive" way is flagging only 2 of 3 instances; again, comparing the value of the xsi:type attribute as text is not the same as comparing **QName** s (which is what @xsi:types are).

Comment: Thanks Petru.  
That would fit my needs but I'm not sure how difficult Schematron validation is. 

Using XMLSpy, it seems that a plugin is required - [XML ValidatorBuddy](http://www.xml-tools.com/valbuddy/help/schematroninxmlspy.htm).

Using oXygen I coudn't make it work (see error message below).  
Engine name: ISO Schematron
Severity: error
Description: The URI urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt does not identify an external Java class

I was also surprised that .NET framework doesn't seems to have its own implementation of Schematron validation [maybe I'm wrong ?].

Comment: I'm afraid GSoap doesn't support it as well, and using soapUI for debug/test purposes, I would have liked it to perform validation on input/ouput messages but it can only validate against XSD's.

Comment: @Eniac, as I've mentioned, I am on .NET which is limited to XSLT1.0 (out of the box). Yes, .NET doesn't have a Schematron built in; however, I've built my own using the XSLTs 1.0 from www.schematron.com, on .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

Just for fun I made an attempt with Schematron ; however I couldn't make it work since the XPath expression I find out uses "current()" which is not available in oxygen or XMLSpy, so I can't test it :(

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" xmlns:ns="http://www.xxx.com" >
        <ns prefix="ns" uri="http://www.xxx.com"/>
        <ns prefix="xs" uri="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <pattern name="AnimalNameUnicity">
                <rule context="Animals/Animal">
                    <assert test="count(//@ns:name[ . = current()]) > 1">name not unique !</assert>        
                </rule>
            </pattern> 
    </schema>
```

Comment: Well, there's more to it... For e.g. ns1:Dog and ns:Dog could be the same if ns1 and ns aliases map to the same namespace, and different if not. My approach would've been different in that I wouldn't use the old version (1.5 here) of the schematron; I would go with the ISO one, more specifically start by writing the XSD constraint for @xsi:type but use the conversion from XSD to Schematron to get the pattern going - see this [link](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2008/12/converting-xml-schemas-to-sche.html) for more information.