# Element agnostic constraints?

Tags: html, xml, xsd

For the XSD I am working with, the markup validated is valid HTML. The rules I am attempting to apply should be able to apply to any HTML element. In other words my rules are element agnostic. I care primarily about constraining attributes.

```
<xs:element name="div">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any>
                    <xs:attribute name="containerColor">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="red"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="blue"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="yellow"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="grey"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="black"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:attribute>
                    <xs:unique name="id" >
                        <xs:selector xpath="*"></xs:selector>
                        <xs:field xpath="*"></xs:field>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:any>
            </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I am new to XSD. I'm sure I have some fundamental misunderstandings.

- *In the above example I want to say any can have (but is not required to have) a "containerColor" attribute. This attribute if used must be one of the enumerated colors.*
- *Additionally any element can have an ID and it should be unique.*

In the above attempt I get complaints that the any element is not a valid context for attribute/unique.

From a selector perspective I care about applying rules I am building to the set of all elements rather than specific ones. Is there a way I can achieve this with XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you can write an XSD schema to do what you want depends on how much of the document you want to constrain, and whether you have any freedom in naming the relevant elements.

In the usual case, attributes are declared in association with particular complex types (and thus indirectly with particular elements) because attributes are very seldom applicable to all elements.  (For example:  is an attribute named containerColor meaningful when it appears on the HTML head and meta elements?  What does it mean then?)

But XSD supports the declaration of top-level attributes.  The following XSD schema declares attributes named `id` and `containerColor` that are not in any namespace.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 

  <xs:attribute name="containerColor">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="red"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="blue"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="yellow"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="grey"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="black"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>

  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>

</xs:schema>
```

They are top-level attributes, not bound to particular elements. So in principle you can hand this schema to an XSD validator with a request that it scan the document, accepting everything for which it does not have an XSD declaration and validating everything for which it does have a declaration.  (The XSD spec refers to this as "lax validation".)  The only declarations it will have are for your two attributes, so it will validate them and pass over everything else.  The effect will be that the attributes you declare are allowed on all elements and validated wherever they occur.

The major hitch here is that XSD makes no attempt to regulate or even define interfaces between validators and the outside world, and there is no guarantee that a given validator that claims conformance with the spec will allow you to invoke it with such a request.  (The up side is that for many XSD validators, lax validation starting at the document element is the default mode of operation, sometimes the only one you can get, so this may well work with whatever validator you are using.)

An alternative is to make a local copy of the XSD schema documents for XHTML and add your attributes to all the elements that should be able to carry them.  XSD 1.1 has some constructs which should make that task easier.

Answer (score 1):

No, what you want cannot be formulated using XSD wildcards. [This link](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-openness) provides a view into what is it you are allowed to do with an xsd:any particle in XSD 1.0, and [this one](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#declare-openness) in XSD 1.1. Basically, the only thing you can nest is an annotation.

If you really have to, you have to use other schema languages. Relax NG is the only of the schema languages (I know of) that can do what you want pretty easily by using the generic name class <anyName> for an <element>. However, it does not (I believe) handles uniqueness - you have to rely on the xsd:ID datatype.

As for uniqueness and Schematron, [have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803048/about-using-xsunique-on-xsitype-in-a-sequence/12803969#12803969), also on SO. If XSD 1.1 is an option, then you can, at least, substitute the Schematron part.